# Problem with \eqalign in newer versions of ConTeXt

Tags: math-mode, context

After updating to ConTeXt ver: 2023.05.05 (LuaTeX) I encountered the following problem: `\eqalign` doesn't seem to work anymore. MWE:

```
\starttext
$\eqalign{
a &= b\cr
b &= c\cr
}$
\stoptext
```

Yields the following error:

```
...
tex error       > tex error on line 2 in file ./text-eqalign.tex: Control sequence expected instead of undefined
<recently read> 
    \eqalign 
<line 3.2> 
    $\eqalign
    {
...
```

Is there a way to make `\eqalign` work again? I know that there exists `\startmathalignment` in ConTeXt, but I have a pretty long document with the `\eqalign` syntax and would like to avoid reformatting everything.

P.S.

I assume this is some new ConTeXt behavior, which I just didn't find information about, and not a bug, since many other things have stopped working as well, but may well be a bug.

Comment: `\eqalign` is not ConTeXt...

Comment: It isn't, but it used to work in ConTeXt just fine up until this version. I totally get it if some plain TeX macros, including this one, no longer work, but maybe there's a way to get it working again.

Comment: Regarding the PS, is that also non-ConTeXt stuff? If not, it might be better to send an email to the context list, to reach out to Hans.

Comment: Interesting, thank you, I didn't think of it, I'll test it with LuaLaTeX tomorrow.

Comment: @mickep at some times it was in context, you find it e.g. in ma-cb-en.pdf.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Well, that document is from... 1999 (or earlier, but was last updated then). To call that ConTeXt and complain that it is not working is a bit like complaining if something LaTeX2.09 is not working properly in modern LaTeX. That said, I spoke to Hans, and it seems that he is willing to move this code back, but maybe into the `oldmath` module. It is simply not meant to be used anymore. There has been [better ways](https://dl.contextgarden.net/myway/mathalign.pdf) for a long time, and nowadays, maybe even more convenient ways with `\alignhere` and `\breakhere`. We move on.

Comment: @mickep  I have no problems with "moving on", but we spoke about the documentation problem in context: ma-cb-en has an not so old copyright date 2017 and it is distributed with context.  So how should a normal user know that it no longer applies in parts?

Comment: OP seems to be aware of the documentation I was linking to, or at least that method, so somehow people seem to find out. Maybe via the garden.

Comment: @SergeySlyusarev Can you try `\setupmathematics[ampersand=normal]`? (You are using luatex, aren't you?)

Comment: @mickep It's the same error with `\setupmathematics[ampersand=normal]`, it's present in my big document mentioned in the original question, but I omitted it here, because it doesn't affect the error message. Also I did check if `\eqalign` works in LuaLaTeX and it does.

Comment: Ok, then you have to wait for an update (worked here, but we have different versions). (Lualatex is irrelevant here)

Comment: @mickep Got it. I thought, maybe, this is an issue on LuaTeX side, and not on ConTeXt side, but, apparently, it's not.