# How to align multiline math equations in ConTeXt when they are inline?

Tags: math-mode, context, inline

Since `\eqalign` [no longer works](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/693853/problem-with-eqalign-in-newer-versions-of-context) in ConTeXt, I'm trying to replace it with `\startalign`/`\stopalign` as described [here](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/images/archive/b/b4/20100530075041!Mathalign.pdf). It works just fine in display mode, but it doesn't seem to be designed to work in inline math mode and my naive version:

```
\starttext
Test $\left\{
  \startalign 
    A\NC=B\NR 
    B\NC=C\NR
  \stopalign 
  \right\}$
\stoptext
```

yields an error: `! You can't use '\halign' in math mode`

The expected result looks like this:
[image: expected result]

What is the correct way to achieve this in ConTeXt?

Comment: For this case specifically, you probably want `\startcases`/`\stopcases`. Not sure about the more general solution though.

Comment: `\startcases`/`\stopcases` does work! But I need to control these curly braces, or remove them at any point, so, ideally, I need something like `\startcases`/`\stopcases`, but without the brace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated** I saw that you also would be happy with some cases construction. Thus, you can try a `simplealign` or some `cases`.

```
\definemathsimplealign
  [sergei]
  [left={\startmathfenced[brace]},
   right={\stopmathfenced}]

\definemathfence
  [foo]
  [left=none,
   right="27E9]

\definemathcases
  [FOO]
  [fences=foo]

\starttext

\startbuffer
\startsergei
  \NC A \EQ B \NR
  \NC B \EQ C \NR
\stopsergei
\stopbuffer

Test $\getbuffer$

\startbuffer
\startFOO
  \NC A \NC B \NR
  \NC B \NC C \NR
\stopFOO
\stopbuffer

Test $\getbuffer$

\stoptext
```

[image: results]

Comment: Thank you! This code doesn't work with version `2023.03.10` (where `\eqalign` still works), I'll check with `2023.05.05` (where `\eqalign` stopped working).

Comment: Strange. The `simplealign` mechanism was introduced in March 2022, or even earlier.

Comment: For me it says `! Undefined control sequence    l.1 \definemathsimplealign` for some reason.

Comment: OK, I don't understand that. It should be in `math-ali.mkxl`.

Comment: Probably it's something on my system, I'll check it on another machine.

Comment: Thank you, this should do the trick. Cases work on my machine, but `\definemathfence` seems to have no effect on the output though. Weird.

Comment: meanwhile, I found out that on my version even `\startcases`/`\stopcases` doesn't work properly: math mode doesn't seem to be applied to the second term (after `\NC`), and produces literally `B^2` instead of `B²` as expected. Is there any chance for `\eqalign` to be made to work in the future, so I can keep backwards compatibility?

Comment: This is getting weirder and weirder. Maybe your installation is broken and you simply need to reinstall? I'm clueless. In any case, I do not think `\eqalign` will be the way to go for ConTeXt.